# Convert time to milliseconds in Excel

Tags: excel, time

I am trying to convert something in the following format to seconds.

Across the first row I have: Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Seconds
Second row I have for example: 2011, 07, 06, 20, 37, 06

How would I convert this to a single cell that specifies the number of total seconds that number is equal to. Keep in mind that different months have different number of days.

Comment: Total seconds to what? You need to specify the time t0. In Unix that would be 1970-01-01 00:00:00. Or do you want the seconds from 0000-01-01 00:00:00.

Comment: So I guess I figured it out. Sorry I should have specified. I have several different rows following the same structure, I wanted the first row to be the t0. Basically I used a vlookup for the number of days there are in each of the months and did some simple subtraction/multiplication

Comment: if you have dates, you wouldn't have to know how many days in each month because while substracting a date from another, you'll get a number of days (and then seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have your values in row 2 and your reference date in G1, then this formula

```
=((DATE(A2,B2,C2)+TIME(D2,E2,F2))-G1)*24*60*60
```

should give you the desired result